# retrieve code snippet data via wsproxy

Tags: ssjs, content-builder, wsproxy

I am trying to retrieve the name and customer key from many content blocks like I do with data estensions

```
var prox1 = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var cols1 = ["Name","CustomerKey"];
var filter1 = {
    Property: "Name",
    SimpleOperator: "like",
    Value: "my_codesnippet_name"
};
var desc = prox1.retrieve("CodeSnippet", cols1, filter1);
```

But this code responses undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All content blocks and assets are stored in Content Builder, which requires the [**Content Builder REST API**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/content-api.html). Since it is utilizing the REST API, this means you cannot use WSProxy as that only uses SOAP API.

So you would need to build a REST API call to retrieve this information and not WSProxy.